# Trigger on delete or update that captures the sender and the command

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to find out who is deleting / updating the data on table THETABLE, the time, using what program, and the command that is sent to the database that caused the modification.

From googling and asking some colleagues, the recommended way is on delete trigger. I know how to create trigger, for example:

```
create trigger whodunit
on THETABLE
for delete
as begin
    insert into MyAuditTbl(moddate, ...
end
```

But how do I get the command that is sent to the DB (query / stored procedure), application name, IP address, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [some script](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1066672.aspx) and customized it to fit my needs:

```
create trigger AuditTHETABLE
    on THETABLE
    for delete, update
as begin
    set nocount on

    declare @shouldlog bit, @insertcount bigint, @deletecount bigint
    select
        @shouldlog = 1,
        @insertcount = (select count(*) from inserted),
        @deletecount = (select count(*) from deleted)

    -- if no rows are changed, do not log
    if @insertcount < 1 and @deletecount < 1 begin
        select @shouldlog = 0
    end

    -- ... other checks whether to log or not

    if @shouldlog = 1 begin
        -- prepare variable to capture last command
        declare @buffer table (
            eventtype nvarchar(30),
            parameters int,
            eventinfo nvarchar(4000)
        )

        -- use DBCC INPUTBUFFER to capture last command
        -- unfortunately only the first 255 characters are captured
        insert @buffer
        exec sp_executesql N'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@@spid) WITH NO_INFOMSGS'

        declare @lastcommand varchar(max)
        select @lastcommand = eventinfo from @buffer

        -- insert into audit table
        insert into myauditlog(
            eventdate, tablename, hostname,
            appname, insertcount, deletecount, command
        ) values(
            getdate(),
            'THETABLE',
            host_name(),
            app_name(),
            @insertcount,
            @deletecount,
            @lastcommand
        )
    end
end
```